# How to understand this result when using std::sort?

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to implement a `PP` class. Please first help check the following imcomplete code:

```
template <typename E>
class PP{
public:
    struct Point2D {
        static int used_count;
        E _x;
        E _y;
        Point2D() : _x(0), _y(0) {
            used_count++;
            std::cout << "Point2D(), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
        }
        virtual ~Point2D() {
            used_count--;
            std::cout << "~Point2D(), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
        }
    };

    std::vector<Point2D> _points;
    int _size;

    PP(int size) : _size(size) {
        _points.resize(_size);
        std::cout << "PP(int size)\n";
    }
    PP(E points[][2], int size)
        : PP(size) {  // Nx2 points
        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++) {
            _points[i]._x = points[i][0];
            _points[i]._y = points[i][1];
        }
        std::cout << "PP(E points[][2])\n";
    }

    virtual ~PP() {
        std::cout << "~PP()\n";
    }

    void Print(const std::string& title) {
        std::cout << title << "\n";
        for (auto iter = _points.begin(); iter != _points.end(); iter++) {
            const Point2D& p = *iter;
            std::cout << p._x << ", " << p._y << "\n";
        }
    }

    void DoSort() {
        std::sort(_points.begin(), _points.end(), [](const Point2D& l, const Point2D& r){ 
            return (l._y > r._y) || (l._y == r._y && l._x > r._x);
        });
    }
};


template<> int PP<int>::Point2D::used_count = 0;
int main() {
      int arr[][2] = {{1, 2},
                      {3, 4},
                      {5, 1},
                      {1, 5},
                      {2, 8},
                      {9, 1},
                      {6, 4},
                      {5, 6}};
      int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

      if (1) {
          PP<int> *t = new PP<int>(arr, size);

          // test sort
          {
              t->Print("before sort");
              t->DoSort();
              t->Print("after sort");
          }

          delete t;
      }
}
```

The result is as follows:

```
  Point2D(), used_count = 1
  Point2D(), used_count = 2
  Point2D(), used_count = 3
  Point2D(), used_count = 4
  Point2D(), used_count = 5
  Point2D(), used_count = 6
  Point2D(), used_count = 7
  Point2D(), used_count = 8
  PP(int size)
  PP(E points[][2])
  before sort
  1, 2
  3, 4
  5, 1
  1, 5
  2, 8
  9, 1
  6, 4
  5, 6
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 7
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 6
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 5
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 4
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 3
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 2
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 1
  after sort
  2, 8
  5, 6
  1, 5
  6, 4
  3, 4
  1, 2
  9, 1
  5, 1
  ~PP()
  ~Point2D(), used_count = 0
  ~Point2D(), used_count = -1
  ~Point2D(), used_count = -2
  ~Point2D(), used_count = -3
  ~Point2D(), used_count = -4
  ~Point2D(), used_count = -5
  ~Point2D(), used_count = -6
  ~Point2D(), used_count = -7
```

My question is, in the `DoSort` function, I just use the `reference` of `Point2D`, what are the reasons that the destructors of `Point2D` are invoked in the `std::sort` routine? What is happened? Could you please help give some advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Beware that your `used_count` doesn't count all instances because you don't count copy construction or move construction.

Comment: `std::sort` probably does a lot of swaps which would each involve creating a temporary copy of `Point2D`. Then each copy would be destroyed after each swap.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thanks a lot for your kind comments. I've updated the question, and it is truly that there are many move constructors are invoked in the `std::sort`.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't update the question with the provided answer.

Comment: @mining I've reverted the update. It is best to leave the solution in the answers section and the unsolved question in the questions section. This helps readability for future readers as this is how Stack Overflow questions are expected to be structured.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, Great, absolutely understood and appreciated! Thank you! I'll follow the Stack Overflow rules in the future for better readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not measuring the copy constructors that are invoked. You can do that by adding:

```
Point2D(Point2D const & p) : _x(p._x), _y(p._y) {
     used_count++;
     std::cout << "Point2D(), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
}
```

If you do that, you get the expected `used_count`.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nKKzo1).

The extra copies are made in the internals of `std::sort` where there are copies made of `Point2D`, when elements are swapped.

Normally `std::sort` would use the move functions in its internals, but the reason you see these unnecessary copies is because you have not defined `move` for your class. If you do that:

```
Point2D(Point2D&& p) : _x(p._x), _y(p._y) {
    std::cout << "Point2D(), used_count = " << used_count << "\n";
    used_count++;
}

Point2D& operator=(Point2D&&) = default;
```

you see that there are no copies made. However, the `used_count` will still osciallate between 8 and 9, in the call to `std::sort`. There are still the same number of temporaries that are created, but these are moved instead of copied, which is more efficient, in general. For this particular class instantiaion, there may not be much of an improvement, since it only contains 2 `int`s, but this is a good habit to get into. e.g. if you instantiate `PP` over `std::string` you can gain a considerable improvement in efficiency.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oEc353).

Comment: Moving a `Point2D` is exactly the same as copying it...

Comment: @user253751 Clarified that this is fine when instantiated with `int`,  but move is better if `PP` is instantiated over an expensive to copy class.

Comment: @cigien, thanks a lot for your detail answer and the explaination. I've updated the question, and it is truly that there are many move constructors are invoked in the `std::sort`.

Comment: No problem. However, as mentioned on your post, it's usually not a good idea to add the answer to the question.

Comment: Yeah, understood. I'll delete the updated section for following the regulations. Thank you!

Comment: @cigien, thanks a lot for your kind suggestions! In fact, I didn't use the move constructors often. I just use the general features of `C++`.

Comment: *I just use the general features of C++* -- Move constructors could be considered "general" enough in this day and age of C++.